# Change position of submenu if it would stretch the page

Tags: html, css

See snippet below. I have a page with a couple of menus. However when a menu is on the right side of the page the part that appears when you hover over it stretches the page and you can't see the items without scrolling the page, as I simulated in the snippet.

Is there a way to prevent this and to have the submenu positioned on the left side if there's no room on the right side?

Thanks!

```css
#body {width: 100px; padding-left: 150px; overflow: auto;}
ul {background-color: gray; width: 100px; margin 0px; padding: 0px; list-style: none;}
li {position: relative; padding: 5px;}
li ul {display: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 100%;}
li:hover {background-color: wheat;}
li:hover ul {display: block;}
span::after {content: "►"; position: absolute; right: 5px;}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>Item 1</span>
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible approaches.

When your element is on the left side is it position fixed? If yes, that means you know where will it be. It means that you can assume what is min-width of viewport to see it's content after hover.
Let's assume it is fixed on left: 800px, it has 100px width and it submenu also has 100px width. Easy calculation shows that you need at least 1000px to see it fully. You can play with @media queries, to optimize it's looks for smaller screens. Pseudo-code:

```
.menu {
   fixed on right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
   .menu {
       somewhere else where it is visible;
   }
}
```

On the other hand, if your menu is not fixed but it is moving with the rest of your page's content, you will have to use javascript. jQuery will simplify your problem - the point is to check if menu will be visible on hover. Use jQuery's .offset and .width() to determine it. If it will not be visible, apply some class that alters it's behavior.

```
if ($(document).width() < $('#float-menu').offset().left + $('#float-menu').width() + $('#float-menu > ul').width()) {
    $('#float-menu').addClass('alternative');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Problem is I have a page with a lot of items, each of which has their own menu. Only the ones that are positioned on the right side of the page have to display the submenu on the left.